# Is there a way to specify and then open a file with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filesystems

I'm attempting to make a program which will allow the user to pick a file from their computer and then open it. I've been trying to do this with Python, and...

```
filedialog.askopenfilenames()
```

...with this Tkinter widget.

I can get the filepath from this successfully, but how to I use it to actually open the file? (I'm trying to open it in its default app, not just print it to the Python console.) I've tried using

```
from subprocess import call
call(['xdg-open','filename'])
```

with 'files' (the variable that the filename is stored in) replacing 'filename', but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charlierubinstein/Documents/Search Engine.py", line 9, in <module>
    call(['xdg-open', files])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from subprocess import call


files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()

call(['xdg-open', files])  
window.mainloop()
```

As stated earlier, ideally this program would let the user pick a file, and then open that file in its default app.

Comment: use `print(files)` to see your mistake

Answer (score 1):

You use `askopenfilenames()` (with **s** at the end of name)

It let you select many files so it returns tuple with all selected files - even if you selected only one file
(or empty tuple if you cancel selection)

So you have to get first element from tuple

```
call(['xdg-open', files[0] ])
```

---

Or use `askopenfilename()` (without **s** at the end of name) and you will get single string.

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename() # without `s` at the end

call(['xdg-open', filename])
```